# Cron job creating empty file each time it runs

Tags: php, cron, wget

I have a php script I want to run every minute to see if there are draft news posts that need to be posted. I was using "wget" for the cron command in cPanel, but i noticed (after a couple days) that this was creating a blank file in the main directory every single time it ran. Is there something I need to stop that from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: What was the filename, and was it sticking around after the job finished?

Comment: i have face some problem. i have created cron job by cpanel. which file i have run same name file have created in root

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When wget runs, by default, it generates an output file, from what I need to remember.

You probably need to use some option of wget, to specify to which file it should write its output -- and use `/dev/null` as destination file *(It's a "special file" that will "eat" everything you can write to it)*

Judging from man wget, the `-O` or `--output-file` option would be a good candidate :

`-O file`

`--output-document=file`

The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file.

so, you might need to use something like this :

```
wget -O /dev/null http://www.example.com/your-script.php
```

And, btw, the output of scripts run from the crontab is often redirected to a logfile -- it can always help.

Something like this might help, about that :

```
wget -O /dev/null http://www.example.com/your-script.php >> /YOUR_PATH_logfile.log
```

And you might also want to redirect the error output to another file *(can be useful, to help with debugging, the day something goes wrong)* :

```
wget -O /dev/null http://www.example.com/your-script.php >>/YOUR_PATH/log-output.log 2>>/YOUR_PATH/log-errors.log
```

Comment: "-q" will turn off Wget's output if you do not need any output.

Comment: @Danny -q is evidently not always enough. my host def needed -O /dev/null in there. Also note that -o is NOT equivalent. The capital "O" must be important on some or all systems.

Comment: `-q` is not working. Cron still creating temporary files on server. Do I need to restart cron after making changes in currently running cron? If yes, then how to do it?